# Objetos idênticos com campos de mesmo valor retornando diferente C#

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, linq, lógica

Objetos idênticos com campos iguais retornando diferente ao comparar com `Equals` ou `==`

```
var oldPayments = orderNotTrack.Payments
                .Where(p => p.Status == Status.Activated)
                .Select(p => new OrderPayment()
                {
                    Guid = p.Guid,
                    CardFlagName = p.CardFlagName,
                    TransactionAmount = Math.Round(p.TransactionAmount, 2),
                    ChangeMoney = p.ChangeMoney,
                    Type = p.Type
                })
                .ToList();
            
            var newPayments = order.Payments.Where(p => p.Status == Status.Activated)
                .Select(p => new OrderPayment()
                {
                    Guid = p.Guid,
                    CardFlagName = p.CardFlagName,
                    TransactionAmount = Math.Round(p.TransactionAmount, 2),
                    ChangeMoney = p.ChangeMoney,
                    Type = p.Type
                })
                .ToList();
```

Estou fazendo a comparação da negação, caso sejam diferentes fazer algo
Segue imagem dos objetos:
[image: Objeto 0]

[image: Objeto1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objetos que não são apontados pelo mesmo endereço de memória são considerados diferentes
O que pode ser feito é fazer um override no Equals da classe
Caso seja uma lista você pode criar uma classe de lista do objeto a ser comparado assim também fazendo o override do seu equals
✌ peace